# Add an indefinite integral with itself by integrating by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I was solving an **indefinite integral** through integration by parts and when developing it I found the same integral which by inertia we can pass them to the same member and add them. This is good? I understand that if it is a **definite integral** this is feasible because they belong to the same integration interval but if it is an indefinite integral, is it viable? What would be a rigorous explanation?

$\int e^{-4t}\cos2tdt= -\dfrac{\cos2t\cdot e^{-4t}}{4} - \dfrac{1}{2} \int\sin2t\cdot e^{-4tdt} $

$\int e^{-4t}\cos2tdt= -\dfrac{\cos2t\cdot e^{-4t}}{4} -\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{-\sin2t\cdot e^{4t}}{4} + \dfrac{1}{2}\int\cos2t\cdot e^{-4t}\right)$

...

$ \dfrac{5}{4} \int e^{-4t}\cos2tdt = \dfrac{\cos2t\cdot e^-4t}{4} + \dfrac{\sin2t\cdot e^{-4t}}{8}$

$\int e^{-4t}\cos2tdt = \dfrac{e^{-4t}(-2\cos2t +\sin2t)}{10} + C$

Comment: Can you show your calculations?

Comment: Yes i just did.

Comment: Thanks. You see main idea is good, but I have doubt in details. Did you check it by derivative? And what is "$sen$" - may be "$sin$"?

Comment: Yes"sen" is sin, sorry and yes I tried it by derivatives but my question is if this method is viable or maybe it is just an artifice.

Comment: You can call it as you want, but idea is correct and you obtain result if everything make correct. I post in answer first step - do you see it?

Comment: Ok I understand. That was my question and thank you very much for taking the trouble to help me.
PD: Sorry, it was cos2t no cost

Answer (score 1):

For first step, taking $u=e^{-4x}$ we have
$$\int e^{-4x} \cos x \, dx= e^{-4x} \sin x +\int 4e^{-4x} \sin x \, dx$$

For second version there is

$$\int e^{-4x} \cos 2x \, dx= \frac{1}{2}e^{-4x} \sin 2x +\int 2e^{-4x} \sin 2x \, dx$$

Comment: Happy to be useful. Do not forget details, please.